# How to Upload Files to Google Drive from a Server?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, google-drive, upload

I am currently the “tech guy” at an office with a very limited and unreliable Internet access. Currently, we take care of all of our document-related work with Google Drive, but with a limited network and 20+ computers all using Google Drive simultaneously.

Is there a way to have all the files get saved to a location on the local network, and then have them uploaded to Google Drive at a certain time to conserve bandwidth during the day when people are working?

Comment: Do you run any server(s) at all now?  20+ seperate google accounts for each user?

Comment: The current OS's are mostly Windows 7-10 and 2 Macs. If I can use a windows solution, that'll be fine though. Currently we do not run any servers, but I believe I could get the parts to set one up. Each user has only one Google account but there are 20+ users.

Answer (score 1):

First you will need a Microsoft Server OS, Linux, or another OS since Desktop versions of Windows will only support 20 connections.

Yes you could setup a User File Share, with each user's directory syncing with different Google Drive account.  For linux you can use [drive](https://github.com/rakyll/drive) and windows,osx,linux [gdrive](https://github.com/rakyll/drive) as examples.  (free opensource)

You can control the command line scripting with those programs to sync when wanted.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to have all the files get saved to a location on the
>   local network, and then have them uploaded to Google Drive at a
>   certain time to conserve bandwidth during the day when people are
>   working?

If you are talking about setting up a “hot folder” of some sort, one nice solution I recently came across is [Rclone](http://rclone.org). Instructions on [how to use Rclone with Google Drive](http://rclone.org/drive/) can be found here:

> Rclone is a command line program to sync files and directories to and
>   from
>
> - Google Drive
> - Amazon S3
> - Openstack Swift / Rackspace cloud files / Memset Memstore
> - Dropbox
> - Google Cloud Storage
> - The local filesystem

Precompiled binaries [for various OS platforms can be found here](http://rclone.org/downloads/). Or if you have the need to compile Rclone from source, [instructions for doing that can be found here as well](http://rclone.org/install/):

> Rclone is a Go program and comes as a single binary file.
>
> Download the relevant binary.
>
> Or alternatively if you have Go installed use
>
> ```
> go get github.com/ncw/rclone
> ```

So if you can get Google’s [Go](https://golang.org) installed in that device—Go downloads [are here](https://golang.org/dl/)—it seems like this would be a nice option to compile from source directly on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completely different solution to your problem.

1. Setup a Squid proxy cache and allocate it 500gb or more.
2. Use QOS to regulate the uploading.  You can set QOS up to guarantee your office workers get a minimum #### kb/s amount.

You will need a spare computer with 2 NIC(s) and IN and OUT.
The same computer can do Squid and QOS on the same machine.